# Google Anthos vs Terraform

Tags: architecture, terraform, cloud, infrastructure, google-anthos

For research, I'm currently looking into Anthos and Terraform and I'm struggling to see a very big difference.

As far as I understood Terraform:

- is used to automate and manage provisioning infrastructure out of / as Code.
- works via API / CLI

For Anthos:

- used to  build, deploy, and manage applications in multiple clouds
- has a Platform (UI) but can be triggered via API

What point am I missing here? Is it just the infrastructure vs application part or is there more?

best Regards
Andre

Answer (score 0):

**Terraform** is Infrastructure as a Code, so you can manage your whole infra by writing `.tf` files and much more. Also, you can even manage your Anthos clusters with Terraform.

**Anthos**, on the other hand, is Google's powerful product so you can manage several Kubernetes clusters (different cloud providers) within one GCP account. So if you don't need multiple clouds, you don't need Anthos at all.

Comment: but can Terraform not also manage multiple K8 cluster? or can it just deploy, resize /scale those ? Or to rephrase it, can Anthos only managed existing cluster or also deploy etc. new ones?

Comment: Anthos is specifically meant for multiple Clouds/OnPremises not just clusters. So you can provision and manage clusters running on AWS and Azure infrastructure through a centralized Google Cloud backed control plane.

Comment: With terraform, you can spin up clusters in both Azure and AWS but you will not find them in the centralized GCP Console view.